# google api & OAuth2 get refresh token

Tags: google-oauth

I have the following code:

```
$this->client = new Google_Client();
$this->client->setAuthConfig(FCPATH . 'google-api-php-client-master'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'client_secret.json');
$this->client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$this->client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
$this->client->setAccessType('offline');
$this->client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
$this->client->setAccessToken($access_token);
if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $this->client->refreshToken($this->client->getRefreshToken());
    print_r($this->client->getAccessToken());
}
```

When I print_r get access token, I got the following array without refresh token:

```
Array
(
    [access_token] => ya29.LwIjjaXB1kGunCp8EzwMwmaO4eoDsqbdoRFNjWhcDvw59RtDnT6mbjlauX3PM6irbMfg
    [token_type] => Bearer
    [expires_in] => 3600
    [created] => 1447747649
)
```

But I want to get such an array with refresh token, for example:

```
Array
(
    [access_token] => ya29.LwIjjaXB1kGunCp8EzwMwmaO4eoDsqbdoRFNjWhcDvw59RtDnT6mbjlauX3PM6irbMfg
    [token_type] => Bearer
    [expires_in] => 3600
    [refresh_token] => 1/wzTZcDm2fzZD9y3Ixr2gczgC5iD1zifVSGQoijCu4vlIgOrJDtdun6zK6XiATCKT
    [created] => 1447747649
)
```

Comment: I think it only returns it the first time.   go to https://plus.google.com/u/0/apps see if your app is there remove it.  Then try again you should get the refresh token.

Comment: where you are retrieving $access_token ??

Comment: When user logins in google from my site I retrieving $access_token. After login in $access_token I have refresh_token, but when access_token is expired I want to get new access_token and refresh_token.

Comment: Thanks all, I already fixed this my problem.